# Difference between UISearchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden and UISearchController.showsSearchResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm currently working with `UISearchController` and I've found out some awkward behavior of `UISearchController`.

Previously I didn't know there was the `showsSearchResultsController` property which helps me to hide `searchResultsController`. So I've tried to manage it by using `searchResultsController?.view.isHidden`. But I've found out that there are infrequent cases where I assigned `true` to `searchResultsController?.view.isHidden` and the view doesn't get hidden.

However, when I used `showsSearchResultsController` and assigned `false` to it, the `searchResultsController` acted as I wanted.

The first code is the code that I used at first (malfunctioned).

Second code is the code that I fixed (worked just fine).

```
isHidden
  .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: true)
  .drive(onNext: { [weak self] in
     print("isHidden Before \($0) \(self?.searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden)")
     self?.appSearchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = $0
     print("isHidden After \($0) \(self?.searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden)")
  })
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

```
isHidden
  .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: true)
  .drive(onNext: { [weak self] in
     print("isHidden Before \($0) \(self?.searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden)")
     self?.appSearchController.showsSearchResultsController = !$0
     print("isHidden After \($0) \(self?.searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden)")
  })
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

In both cases the output of print was

```
isHidden Before false Optional(false)
isHidden After false Optional(true)
```

By using `showsSearchResultsController` I've fixed the problem, but I really want to know the difference between two. In my point of view I think two codes look similar. Sharing ideas would be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `showsSearchResultsController` property is the far better approach. It's part of the public API provided by `UISearchController`. Setting that property allows the search controller to do whatever it deems as appropriate to show/hide the search results. This likely involves much more than simply showing/hiding a view.

When you do something like `searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = someBool`, you are digging into the (arguably) private substructure of the search controller. You are bypassing the public API. You likely lose some nuances or finesse that is gained by using the public API provided by `showsSearchResultsController`.

A future version of iOS may change the look and feel of `UISearchController` and the search results view. By using the public API your code should continue to function correctly. Digging into the guts of the search controller's view directly could result in incorrect behavior or a bad user interface.